# .NET Lines of Code Counter

Tags: c#, .net

I was wondering if anyone could recommend a good LOC counter for .NET projects (web, windows service, etc.)?  Some features that I'm looking for include:

- Ability to export results to Excel or
  something similar (not just PDF as I
  may want to work with the data);
- Create several counter projects (e.g. project 1 includes .NET
  projects A,B and C, and project 2
  includes .NET projects D, E and F);
- Be able to track changes to projects over time;
- Easily weed out bogus files (like VSS files, csproj files, .user files,
  etc.);
- Count code against TFS, VSS , file system;
- Ideally, I'd like to be able to point the app to a .sln file and have
  it import all projects, instead of me
  having to add each project one by
  one;
- Include JavaScript files (and ideally exclude comments, but that's a nice-to-have);
- **EDIT** Freeware would be preferred but not a show-stopper;
- **EDIT** Support for .NET 3.5 and 4 is required.

I saw a few older questions along the same line, but was hoping for some updated tools that support various types of .NET projects (not just web projects, for example).

Thanks in advance!

Comment: if you're using VS2008, have you tried the one that comes with it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Would this [project](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/macros/LineCounterAddin.aspx) found on CodeProject do? - and has been updated for VS 2005/2008.

Comment: Any reason it wouldn't support VS2010?  I haven't looked at it yet - just asking.  Thanks!!

Answer (score 11):

Visual Studio 2008 and 2010 has a code analyzer built in. In the solution explorer right click on the project and pick Calculate Code Metrics.
You can read more here http://blogs.msdn.com/b/habibh/archive/2009/10/27/how-to-count-the-lines-of-code-loc-in-your-application-using-visual-studio.aspx

Raul

Comment: This is not available on all versions of 2008/2010. Only premium and above

Comment: It is available on 2013 Professional though.

Answer (score 4):

[Source Monitor](http://www.campwoodsw.com/sourcemonitor.html) does much of what you are looking for. I don't believe it works against any version control systems, but can be accessed through scripts. It does not work with JavaScript. I've used it on a number of projects and been happy with it.

Answer (score 4):

I usually use NDepend for code analysis it does have LOC as one of the metrics and support quite a few of your requirements (such as point at .sln file). No build in support for Version control systems but it is supported by quite a few continuous integration servers.